# Canvases content is lost when the context is lost

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, webgl2

I want to draw on canvases (more than 100) and have their content preserved. My setup is that I create canvases in a loop, and for each one I get the `webgl2` context of it and do some drawing. The problem is, that after 16 canvases, when i get the `webgl2` context from the 17th, the first one shows a missing image logo

[image]

I first thought that I should gracefully free up and release the context, but after googling a while, my only luck was to find some hack to call `loseContext()` on an extension, which ended in making the canvas look like the one in the image right after the call.

I also tried deleting all the resources used in the context (like buffers, programs and etc.) but no luck there either.

So, how do I achieve that? Is it possible at all?

Comment: My I ask, why do you need 100 canvases?

Comment: My safest answer would be to test something. Not sure if I'm allowed to give you more detailed answer.

Comment: I'm just having a hard time imagining what task may require having so many `canvases` at the same time. You can always render multiple things using a single `canvas`. JS is not multi-threaded, so you cannot draw simultaneously on 100 canvases or even in batches. I don't see any practical use for this, TBH, and this makes me think that your task can be approached in another way without 100 canvases. By creating 100 or more canvases, you can only test if a browser can handle this, and it seems that it cannot and probably shouldn't.

Comment: @RAllen suppose I'm testing exactly that, whether the browser can or cannot handle that. My question still remains the same. Why the canvas drops it's content when the context drawing on the canvas is lost. Let's focus on the question and not why am I trying to have 100 canvases. Though, I cannot not appreciate your effort in trying to help me solve the problem using a different approach.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [WebGL Fundamentals](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-multiple-views.html#:%7E:text=Another%20issue%20is%20most%20browsers,that%20covers%20the%20entire%20window.) most browsers support only 8 webgl contexts simultaneously.

Chromium had a [registered request](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=771792) to make a number of contexts adjustable. They also stated that it is not easy to make this value configurable because the actual contexts are tightly connected with hardware and, if exceeded, can make the video driver stop.

However, the new config value `--max-active-webgl-contexts=32` was introduced, and the official default value for Chromium is 16.

There is also [a project](https://github.com/greggman/virtual-webgl) that allows virtualizing WebGL contexts, but it is not clear what impact its usage may have.

To summarize:

1. The number of contexts is browser and hardware dependent
2. It cannot be changed via JS
3. In most scenarios, it is assumed that only 1 context is used

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: That helps a lot. But is there anything we know about why the content of the canvas goes blank when the webgl context is released?

Comment: I can only speculate that there is head-tail buffer, and once a new context is requested and the total number of allocated contexts exceeds the maximum, the oldest one is released. Some other reasons are mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25219352/webgl-scene-doest-render-because-of-lost-context

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that each browser limits the amount of active (webgl) contexts. As you found out yourself, with Chromium-based browsers the limit is 16, while in Firefox it's 300 for example.
If you exceed this limit, the browser will start throwing away the oldest contexts, what means that it frees up **all** resources related to that particular context, including the backbuffer used to store it's pixeldata. On Chrome you'll get a warning like:

> WARNING: Too many active WebGL contexts. Oldest context will be lost.

Unfortunately the amount of contexts can't be changed. What you can do depends on your definition of `preserving content`. If it means you want to backup the contents of it's backbuffer, you can workaround like this:

1. While creating the canvases and it's contexts keep a counter of active contexts and store a reference to those inside an array e.g. `canvases=[]`
2. If the number of active contexts exceeds a magic number - let's say **16** - get the context 16 elements before the current from the `canvases` array
3. Create a new canvas with a **2d** context and copy the pixeldata from the `webgl` canvas using `drawImage()`
4. Using the `WEBGL_lose_context` extension, get rid of the old webgl context
5. Wait until it emits the `webglcontextlost` event, so you know it's save to create a new webgl context
6. Replace the old canvas with the webgl context by the just copied clone

Here's an example of generating 64 webgl contexts in the aforementioned way:

```js
const MAX_CONTEXTS = 16;

(async() => {
  let canvas, context;
  let width = 40;
  let height = 40;
  let canvases = [];
  let oldCanvas;
  for (let a = 0; a < 64; a++) {
    if (canvases.length >= MAX_CONTEXTS) {
      oldCanvas = canvases[canvases.length - MAX_CONTEXTS];
      canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      canvas.width = width;
      canvas.height = height;
      context.drawImage(oldCanvas.canvas, 0, 0);

      oldCanvas.context.getExtension("WEBGL_lose_context").loseContext();
      await new Promise(resolve => {
        oldCanvas.canvas.addEventListener('webglcontextlost', resolve);
      });
      document.body.insertBefore(canvas, oldCanvas.canvas);
      canvas.id = oldCanvas.canvas.id;
      document.body.removeChild(oldCanvas.canvas);
    }
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.id = a;
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    context = canvas.getContext("webgl", {
      preserveDrawingBuffer: true
    });
    context.viewport(0, 0, context.drawingBufferWidth, context.drawingBufferHeight);
    context.clearColor(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1.0);
    context.clear(context.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    canvases.push({
      canvas: canvas,
      context: context
    });
  }
})();
```